# Equal not throwing error during list comparison in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a table

```
t:([] s:`GOOG`APPL;d:2?.z.d ;t:2?.z.t)
```

I'd use =  while selecting a single record :

```
q)select from t where s=`GOOG
s    d          t           
----------------------------
GOOG 2017.01.25 04:30:47.898
```

**However I am expecting an error**  while selecting multiple records using '=' because I should be using 'in' , but it is returning the correct data rather than throwing any error :

```
q)select from t where s=`GOOG`APPL
s    d          t           
----------------------------
GOOG 2017.01.25 04:30:47.898
APPL 2007.12.27 04:07:38.923
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case you are comparing a vector to an atom. `=` is overloaded for this operation, so it will compare each element in the vector to that atom

```
q)t[`s]
`GOOG`APPL

q)t[`s]=`GOOG
10b
```

In the second case, where you expect the error,  `=` is doing a vector to vector comparison. **Since the length of both vectors are the same it works and does not throw a `length` error** :

```
q)t[`s]=`GOOG`APPL
11b
```

Changing the order won't return anything due to the element by element comparison :

```
q)t[`s]=`APPL`GOOG
00b
```

e.g. for the following table with 3 elements

```
t:([] s:`GOOG`APPL`HP;d:3?.z.d ;t:3?.z.t)
q)t[`s]
`GOOG`APPL`HP
```

you'd get a `length` error

```
q)t[`s]=`GOOG`APPL
'length
```

and therefore using `in` would fix the error

```
q)t[`s] in `GOOG`APPL
110b
```